Spring Authorization Server - Failed making field 'java.time.Instant#seconds' accessible
I am trying to build a custom authorization server using spring oauth2 authorization server.
Java: 17
Spring boot Version: 3.3.1
dependencies:

spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server

spring-boot-starter-security

spring-boot-starter-web

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

mysql-connector-j


I created a bean of OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> which looks like
@Bean
public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtTokenCustomizer(JdbcUserInfoService jdbcUserInfoService) {
    return (context) -> {
        if (OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType())) {
            context.getClaims().claims((claims) -> {
                Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(context.getPrincipal().getAuthorities())
                        .stream()
                        .map(c -> c.replaceFirst("^ROLE_", ""))
                        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), Collections::unmodifiableSet));
                claims.put("roles", roles);
            });
        }

        if (OidcParameterNames.ID_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType().getValue())) {
            OidcUserInfo userInfo = jdbcUserInfoService.loadByUsername(context.getPrincipal().getName());
            context.getClaims().claims((claims) -> {
                context.getAuthorizedScopes().forEach((scope) -> {
                    switch (scope) {
                        case OidcScopes.EMAIL:
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.EMAIL, userInfo.getEmail());
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.EMAIL_VERIFIED, userInfo.getEmailVerified());
                            break;
                        case OidcScopes.PHONE:
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.PHONE_NUMBER, userInfo.getPhoneNumber());
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.PHONE_NUMBER_VERIFIED, userInfo.getPhoneNumberVerified());
                            break;
                        case OidcScopes.ADDRESS:
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.ADDRESS, userInfo.getAddress());
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.EMAIL, userInfo.getEmail());
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.PHONE_NUMBER, userInfo.getPhoneNumber());
                            break;
                        case OidcScopes.PROFILE:
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.NAME, userInfo.getPreferredUsername());
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.FAMILY_NAME, userInfo.getFamilyName());
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.GIVEN_NAME, userInfo.getGivenName());
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.MIDDLE_NAME, userInfo.getMiddleName());
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.PICTURE, userInfo.getPicture());
                            claims.put(StandardClaimNames.UPDATED_AT, userInfo.getUpdatedAt());
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}

UserInfoEntity looks like:
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user_details`")
public class UserInfoEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column(unique = true, length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String givenName;
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String familyName;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String middleName;
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String picture;
    @Column(length = 100, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    private Boolean emailVerified;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Boolean phoneNumberVerified;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthdate;
    private TimeZone zoneInfo;
    private Locale locale;
    @Column(length = 500)
    private String address;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedAt;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

    public enum Gender {
        MALE,
        FEMALE,
        PREFER_NOT_TO_SAY;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void defaults() {
        Date currentDate = Date.from(Instant.now());
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        if (this.createdAt == null)
            this.createdAt = currentDate;
        this.updatedAt = currentDate;

        if (this.gender == null)
            this.gender = Gender.PREFER_NOT_TO_SAY;
    }
}

JdbcUserInfoService:
import in.anekdote.authn.entity.UserInfoEntity;
import in.anekdote.authn.repository.JdbcUserInfoRepository;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcUserInfo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@Service
public class JdbcUserInfoServiceImpl implements JdbcUserInfoService {
    private final JdbcUserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

    public JdbcUserInfoServiceImpl(JdbcUserInfoRepository userInfoRepository) {
        this.userInfoRepository = userInfoRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public OidcUserInfo loadByUsername(String username) {
        UserInfoEntity userInfoEntity = this.userInfoRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(username));

        return this.getOidcUserInfoFromEntity(userInfoEntity);
    }

    private OidcUserInfo getOidcUserInfoFromEntity(UserInfoEntity userInfoEntity) {
        String birthdate = null;
        String zoneInfo = null;
        String locale = null;
        String updatedAt = null;

        if (userInfoEntity.getBirthdate() != null) {
            birthdate = this.dateToString(new Date(userInfoEntity.getBirthdate().getTime()));
        }

        if (userInfoEntity.getZoneInfo() != null) {
            zoneInfo = userInfoEntity.getZoneInfo().getDisplayName();
        }

        if (userInfoEntity.getLocale() != null) {
            locale = userInfoEntity.getLocale().getDisplayName();
        }

        if (userInfoEntity.getUpdatedAt() != null) {
            updatedAt = this.dateToString(new Date(userInfoEntity.getUpdatedAt().getTime()));
        }

        return OidcUserInfo.builder()
                .subject(userInfoEntity.getUsername())
                .preferredUsername(userInfoEntity.getUsername())
                .givenName(userInfoEntity.getGivenName())
                .familyName(userInfoEntity.getFamilyName())
                .middleName(userInfoEntity.getMiddleName())
                .picture(userInfoEntity.getPicture())
                .email(userInfoEntity.getEmail())
                .emailVerified(userInfoEntity.getEmailVerified())
                .phoneNumber(userInfoEntity.getPhoneNumber())
                .phoneNumberVerified(userInfoEntity.getPhoneNumberVerified())
                .gender(userInfoEntity.getGender().name())
                .birthdate(birthdate)
                .zoneinfo(zoneInfo)
                .locale(locale)
                .address(userInfoEntity.getAddress())
                .updatedAt(updatedAt)
                .build();
    }

    private String dateToString(Date date) {
        if (date != null) {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
            return dateFormat.format(date);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

When I am trying to fetch tokens I am getting below error:
com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.time.Instant#seconds' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
See https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#reflection-inaccessible
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:76) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:388) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:161) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:628) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:57) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:222) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:154) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:944) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:899) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:848) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:825) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.JSONObjectUtils.toJSONString(JSONObjectUtils.java:541) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.Payload.toString(Payload.java:363) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.Payload.toBytes(Payload.java:395) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.Payload.toBase64URL(Payload.java:412) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject.composeSigningInput(JWSObject.java:193) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject.<init>(JWSObject.java:112) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT.<init>(SignedJWT.java:60) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.39.3.jar:9.39.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder.serialize(NimbusJwtEncoder.java:146) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder.encode(NimbusJwtEncoder.java:111) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:187) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:61) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator.generate(DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator.java:59) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:267) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]

I tried two things:

To resolve this issue, I wrote a custom TypeAdapter for the Instant class to handle its serialization and deserialization.
I tried to add module-info.java file in my project module and tried to open the java.time to com.nimbusds.jose

None the solution worked

java LocalDate was released with java 8 on the 18th of March 2014, thats 10 years ago, which in tern sort of deprecated java.util.Date and java.sql.Date so why are you using them?

I suggest that you avoid using Date. Instead use:

in your entities (domain objects persisted in the database with JPA) use:

LocalDate for calendar dates defining a day (like birthdate)
Instant for timestamps (like createdAt & updatedAt)


in DTOs (HTTP requests payloads), use:

String for calendar dates (ISO format: yyyy/MM/dd)
Long for timestamps (epoch second or milli second depending on the desired precision and constraint from OAuth2 / OpenID standards)



All frameworks have constructors for calendar dates from ISO format and for timestamps from epoch (milli)second and will (de)serialize payloads with ease and no ambiguity.
Also, if you read the OpenID standard, you'll see that claims issued by your authorization server must follow the advice I give above for DTOs.
